# Upload Azure VM snapshot to Azure Blob Storage directly without saving VHD to local computer

Tags: azure, url, azure-blob-storage

We are taking over a VM image from another subscription, which we cannot access via the portal, so the snapshot download link is all we have.

I don't have enough disk storage on my computer to download the VHD from the download link provided by Azure so I'm wondering if there is a way to upload a file from URL directly to an Azure container? The image is roughly 120 gb.

The SAS url looks something like this:

https://{something}.blob.storage.azure.net/{something}/{something}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link was helpful for me. Task was done without installing azcopy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-powershell-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a SAS URI for your VM's Snapshot, you can use [`Copy Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob) functionality to perform server-side copy operation which will copy blob from one storage account to another without the need to download it locally.

You can use [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) tool to perform this operation.

Comment: Many thanks Gaurav! I managed to do it in the console using the following command: azcopy cp "source SAS URI" "destination SAS URI"

Comment: Awesome. Please make sure to wait for the copy operation to complete before deleting source blob.